# Unable to read XML tags with '-' using SimpleXMLElement in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read an XML file with tags with '-' using my PHP code. My XML file looks like this:
when i read through headelement without hyphen and change in my xml file it is readable but when hyphen is there, it is not readable and gives me error :

( ! )SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in myfile

```
<root>
   <head-element>
    ...
    ...
    ...
   </head-element>
    <head-element>
    ...
    ...
    ...
   </head-element>
</root>
```

My php code for reading the XML file is:

```
try 
{ 
    /*** a new dom object ***/ 
    $xml = new domDocument;         
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;   

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('root.xml'); 
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML()); 

    $nodes = $sxe->head-element[0];
    $user = $nodes->addchild("new-element"); 
    $user->addChild("uuid", "a1234");
    echo $sxe->asXML(); 
} 
catch( Exception $e ) 
{ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try accessing your xml nodes using:

```
$xml = new domDocument;         
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;   

$xml = simplexml_load_file('root.xml'); 
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML()); 

//the way you can read your custom nodes
$nodes = $sxe->{'head-element'}[0];
```

Hope it helps.